# Can I add custom middleware to the dev server in an Angular CLI app?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Essentially, I'd like to extend the Angular CLI's proxy to enable some custom Express middleware our organization uses to support a unique authentication model.

[Create React App supports this](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually) by exposing the Express app instance, and letting you `app.use()` your own middleware.

I can't find a way to support this with the Angular CLI. Is this feasible without ejecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported with an Angular (8+) custom builders.

In particular, the [custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) builder lets you integrate in custom middleware, using Webpack's `before` hook.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverbefore

For example, make an `extra-webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    before(app, server) {
      app.use(yourCustomMiddleware);
    }
  }
};
```

Then wire it up in `angular.json`:

```
"architect": {
  ...
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser"
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
         path: "./extra-webpack.config.js"
      }
```